# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) and Undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, linker-errors

i have problem, and i can't figure out why..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QButtonElement", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QEntryElement", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QRootElement", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QSection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you have a file named QButtonElement.m in your project? Is it assigned to your target? Or maybe there is some library you forgot to add that have those four classes.

Comment: I figured it out, i still used the QButtonElement in code even if i already deleted the class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i still used the QButtonElement in code even if i already deleted the class..